# Pull/Call the results of a Zapier trigger

Tags: zapier

I am trying to pull the results of another trigger (fields) to then be appended to the endpoint for another trigger. Basically trying to get the custom fields. I may also need to rule out any NULL fields. I have used bundle.inputdata before, but not sure if I need to use that or maybe something like bundle.outputData? The trigger is custom_fields.

Here is what I tried:

```
const options = {
  url: 'https://edapi.zyx.com/v1/Subscribers?PageSize=2&Fields={bundle.outputData.custom_fields}',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking to implement Custom/Dynamic Fields.
To accomplish this, you'll want to create a function that makes a request to your endpoint and returns an array of objects like -

[{"key":"field_1"},{"key":"field_2"}]

Add that function at the end of your inputfields array and once we're done listing the static fields, we'll call and load each returned array index as a custom field.

You should be able to parse out any null values in your function as well before returning.

You can get some additional information here -

https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform/tree/master/packages/cli#customdynamic-fields

Comment: I am working with someone on that aspect, but we are hitting numerous roadblocks since the endpoint is not very friendly. I thought that if I could pull in the result of a working trigger, it would be easier. I will look into it further.